# How can I access the complex json object value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

I have an array object that is below.

```
var user = [
  {name: 'Corbin', age: 20, location: 'USA'},
  {name: 'prashant', age: 20, location: 'india'}
];
```

and I have to capture all the names from the user object i.e.

```
Corbin
prashant
```

and I am trying this....

```
alert(user.name);
```

it gives undefined alert,so please give me proper suggestion for this problem,

thanks,

Comment: First `user` is an array.

Comment: This is not JSON. It's just a Javascript array. Iterate it the same as you would any array

Comment: yes this is an array.

Comment: @prush please take a look at my answer and consider accepting it if it helps you or drop any comments if there's anything unclear with it.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to loop over the array and just access the `name` property for each iterated object, using `.name` :

```js
var users = [{name: 'Corbin', age: 20, location: 'USA'}, {name: 'prashant', age: 20, location: 'india'}];

for (user in users) {
  alert(users[user].name);
}
```

You can use either the simple `for loop` or a `for..in` loop as shown in the code to loop over the array.

Answer (score 0):

It's an array so you have to iterate over it to get to the individual users; following code will alert every username:

```js
var users = [
   {name: 'Corbin', age: 20, location: 'USA'},
   {name: 'prashant', age: 20, location: 'india'}
];
for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
   alert(users[i].name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you are just trying to access data with alert, but I didn't understood what you were meaning about capturing, so I assume you must get names in seperate array?

```
var names = [];

for(var i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
    names.push(user[i].name);
}
```

Then you get this:

```
names = ["Corbin", "prashant"];
```

And can access names by its index in array (starts from 0)